# Using Restlet ClientResource Get API with generic type

Tags: generics, restlet, restlet-2.0

I want to pass in a generic type to the ClientResource get API. I am calling the following Restlet API and receiving an error.

```
SearchHit<T> result = new ClientResource(URL).get(new TypeReference<SearchHit<T>>(){}.getClass());
Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#1-of ? extends new TypeReference<SearchHit<T>>(){} to SearchHit<T>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the following works. new ClientResource(URL).get(new SearchHit<T>().getClass());